# Not able to uninstall old version of phpunit

Tags: php, xampp, phpunit, composer-php, pear

I've installed PHPUnit via composer by running the following command:

```
composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.8.*"
```

I noticed that there is an old version of phpunit(version 3.7.21) installed which comes with xampp for Windows. I'm trying to uninstall it by running the following command:

```
pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
```

which fails with the error message: **unknown channel "phpunit" in phpunit/PHPUnit**.

When I run `phpunit -v` it shows the version as 3.7.21 and the command `where phpunit` gives the following result:

[image]

**How do I uninstall phpunit in xampp?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somehow your PEAR environment does not know the `pear.phpunit.de` channel server yet has packages installed from it.

As that [PEAR channel server does not exist anymore](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method), there is no way of making it known to your PEAR environment (as `pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de` will no longer work).

Looks like you have to manually delete all PHPUnit-related files that were installed using the PEAR installer.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I just removed the files named `phpunit`(one file and one batch file) form xampp/php directory. Now the old version is no longer recognized.